# How to add LLVM to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, llvm

Installed LLVM 10 on Win 10 machine, which already had VS2019-Enterprise.

Created the Directory.build.props file as:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LLVMInstallDir>full_path_to_my_llvm</LLVMInstallDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Ran MSBuild while on the directory that contains *.sln* and *.vxproj* files.

Still cannot get see llvm under ConfigurationProperties->General->PlatformToolset.

How does one add LLVM to VS2019?

Comment: You are using the current version of Visual Studio and have installed the appropriate [additional components](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/)?

Comment: @Ramhound I have installed Desktop Development with C++. I am seeing CLang 3.7 but  I would like to use LLVM 10 which I have downloaded separetely. I also have Intel C++ 15 and 16 that I had installed prior to VS2019(16.5.1 Enterprise) and they show up in PlatformToolset selection. How can I get the LLVM 10 to show up there?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/clang-support-msbuild?view=msvc-170, install "MSBuild support for LLVM (clang-cl) toolset" or "C++ Clang-cl for V142 build tools(X64/x86)", depends on your vc version. Then llvm (clang-cl) will appear in platformToolSet. After that, you can use Directory.build.props to change the path to your own llvm/clang folder.